# Select 6 items while maximizing values under constraints

Tags: excel, solver

I have numerous data points of items of which have a predetermined price-tag associated with them as well as a self calculated return value of each item. I'm looking to select 6 of the 100+ items in order to maximize the total return value while keeping the total price of the 6 items within a $50,000 constraint. I've tried different solutions using the solver tool but was unable to get the result I was looking for - however I am not very knowledgeable with solver.

[image: first 25 rows of data points]

Comment: How can you vote to close this as there is sufficient information given in the question to enable a solution to be provided. And, btw, it only took me a couple of minutes to build - the image upload took longer...

Comment: As a good point to get this question reopened: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: And [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, only used a small data set as you posted an image and I am not spending time typing all the data you put in the image.

Have a look at this:

[image]

So, two sumproducts and a sum do the work, binary and two constraints in the solver. You might be wanting to check out the effects of "=" or ">=" for the number of items chosen.