# determine the best purchase products from different stores with vba

Tags: excel, vba

using vba in excel with datasheet with different stores offering products, how can i determine the best purchase of different products from different stores by grouping the products for a minimum purchase of $ 30.00 from each store?

without buying the same product several times
so far I have not found a solution
sorry for my English

**example table:**

**shop pro1 prd2- prd3- prd4- prd5** 
**--A--** 00,00 10,00 11,00 13,00 00,00
**--B--** 12,00 00,00 12,00 12,00 10,00
**--C--** 11,00 12,00 10,00 11,00 00,00
**--D--** 10,00 10,00 00,00 11,00 00,00
**--E--** 13,00 11,00 00,00 00,00 10,00

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try using the Solver.

Comment: Have a look at the the answer I gave here, but you will have to edit it to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424379/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can use Solver in Excel to find the combination of products, that add to a specific value. Taking away the idea that these numbers are products and stores, the concept you're looking for is a many to one relationship of ledger entries, totally a net 30$.

Solver in this example I googled, can do that if you set it up and learn the steps.
[Solver example for many to one recon](https://thedailycpa.com/2017/07/21/identifying-excel-entries-that-add-up-to-a-specific-value/)